# How to get 2 images inside flexbox items to full screen width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: 1 image is full-width]

I cannot get both images to be the same width with a relative position.
Both images are placed inside a flexbox container, and then placed in another div, item 1 and item 2 respectively.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!-- parliament background -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img
      class="img3"
      src="pictures/1920px-Parliament_of_Hungary_November_2017.jpg"
      alt=""
      style="width: 100%"
    />
  </div>
  <!-- parliament end -->
  <!-- mountain background -->
  <div class="item2">
    <img
      class="img4"
      src="pictures/output-onlinepngtools.png"
      alt=""
      style="width: 100%"
    />
  </div>
  <!-- mountain end -->
</div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
/* parliament photo */
.img3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 20%;
}

/* mountain photo */
.img4 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: The children of your flex container currently have no reason to grow wider than the images naturally are, you need to add `flex-grow: 1` for those.

Comment: Like this?  https://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/GRXQXJb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.img3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 20%;
}

/* mountain photo */
.img4 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width:100vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.item1{
  width:100vw;
   
}
.item2{
  width:100vw;

}
```

```html
<!-- parliament background -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img
      class="img3"
      src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/03/05/14/00/motion-7831456_960_720.jpg"
      alt=""
      
    />
  </div>
  <!-- parliament end -->
  <!-- mountain background -->
  <div class="item2">
    <img
      class="img4"
      src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/852010454/photo/motion-speed-light-tail-with-night-city-background.webp?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=ad5gYPia7h80wQ_tNqdvYdyUbcbLwDWcNikhn9zYW0o="
      alt=""
      
    />
  </div>
  <!-- mountain end -->
</div>
```

Comment: While giving answer you should include things about your code or the point which solved the question. Please just don't post the code without any information or else it won't be useful for other with same issue.